# How to match String with Number in VBA

Tags: loops, if-statement, do-while

Hope someone can help me with this.

Objective:I am trying to match 2 cells of information where,

Cell 1 data: Chicken1234
Cell 2 data: 1234

Cell 2 will determine how many characters of cell 1 from the right to be used for the matching criteria. 
Therefore in excel context it should be =if(cell2=(right(cell1,len(cell2)),"True","False")

Please tell me what am I doing wrong and how I can better this.

sample data:

**Meat    |Chicken1234 |Answer True or False**

**MeatNo  |1234        |Answer True or False**

```
Sub matchingtest()

Dim MTAC As Variant, BankAC As Variant


[A1].Select

MeatNo = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)
No = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)

Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))

    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) And _
        No = MeatNo Then _

            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).FormulaR1C1 = ("True")
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Else

           ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).FormulaR1C1 = ("False")
           ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    End If

Loop



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic example could be like this(not tested):

```
myMeats = Array("Chicken", "Porc", "Beef")
Function CheckMeat(compareTo as String)
  For i = 0 To UBound(myMeats)
    Dim TestComp As Integer
    ' The two strings sort equally. Returns 0.
    TestComp = StrComp(myMeats[i], compareTo, CompareMethod.Text)
    ' -1 string1 is in string2, 0 equal, +1 string2 is in string1
    If TestComp = -1 or TestComp = 0 or TestComp = 1 Then
      return true
    End If
  End For
End Function
```

From:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/9s233cfc(v=vs.90).aspx
http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut01.htm
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/485383-define-list-values-within-visual-basic-applications-code.html